# Sun PKCS11 library C_Encrypt and C_Decrypt changes

Tags: java, 32-bit, sunpkcs11

Up until now I was using **C_Encrypt** and **C_Decrypt** methods of Sun PKCS11 Wrapper smoothly. It was;

```
C_Encrypt(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7)  # requiring 7 parameters
```

But after upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04, my Java updated to 1.8.0_275 build.  Now it requires 9 parameters;

```
public native int C_Encrypt(long var1, long var3, byte[] var5, int var6, int var7, long var8, byte[] var10, int var11, int var12) throws PKCS11Exception;
```

I cannot find any documentation online to how to use new wrapper functions. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/jdk.crypto.cryptoki/share/classes/sun/security/pkcs11/wrapper/PKCS11.java) you can find the latest version OpenJDK has released.

After the updates that come with PKCS11 v2.40 version, C_Encrypt and C_Decrypt methods requires 9 parameters. You can find the details [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/commit/8813b93095b5ca339f5ee54732af00a0135426aa).